# How to get events from one stream which happened after the last event from other stream

Tags: javascript, angular, reactive-programming, rxjs, rxjs5

There are two streams, which never completes:

```
--a---b-c-d---e--f---->

-----1-------2------3-->
```

I want to get events from the first stream which happened after the last event from the second stream.

At the beginning it looks like this:

```
--a->
 (?)
---->
 (=)
--a->
```

After the second stream emits first event it looks like this:

```
--a---b-c-d->
    (?)
-----1------>
    (=)
------b-c-d->
```

After a new event in the second stream:

```
--a---b-c-d---e--f->
        (?)
-----1-------2----->
        (=)
--------------e--f->
```

And so on... Which set of operators needed to do this?

Comment: This is a great question! I'm going to take a look at this [RxJS 5 Operators By Example:  combineLatest](https://gist.github.com/btroncone/d6cf141d6f2c00dc6b35#combinelatest) to see if I can come up with something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [CombineLatest](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/combinelatest.md) to return the events as you would like, for example:

```
/* Have staggering intervals */
var source1 = Rx.Observable.interval(1000)
    .map(function(i) {

        return {
            data: (i + 1),

            time: new Date()
        };
    });

var source2 = Rx.Observable.interval(3000).startWith(-1)
    .map(function(i) {

        return {
            data: (i + 1),
            time: new Date()
        };
    });

// Combine latest of source1 and source2 whenever either gives a value with a selector
var source = Rx.Observable.combineLatest(
    source1,
    source2,
    function(s1, s2) {

        if (s1.time > s2.time) {
            return s1.data + ', ' + s2.data;
        }

        return undefined;
    }
).filter(x => x !== undefined).take(10);

var subscription = source.subscribe(
    function(x) {
        console.log('Next: %s', x);
    },
    function(err) {
        console.log('Error: %s', err);
    },
    function() {
        console.log('Completed');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% on your marbles since they seem somewhat contradictory, but I would propose an alternative which is to use [`window`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/operator/window.ts) or [`buffer`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/operator/buffer.ts) if all you need is to group events together that occurred after an event from the second source.

```
var count = 0;
//Converts the source into an Observable of Observable windows
source1.window(source2).subscribe(w => {
  var local = count++;
  //Just to show that this is indeed an Observable
  //Subscribe to the inner Observable
  w.subscribe(x => console.log(local + ': ' + x));
});
```

Note this only emits the values from the first source, if you want them combined with the other source's values then by all means use `combineLatest` or `withLatestFrom` as suggested by the other answers.